# getting the EC2 Instance List and the networkIn networkOut data by using AWS SDK JavaScript

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to using AWS-SDK For JavaScript to generate a monthly report of EC2 Instance for own use. I want to get the last month usage data by using CloudWatchClient and EC2Client.

```
    const getEC2Instances = async (regions) => {
    const EC2Clients = new EC2Client(myClient(regions));
    const EC2Command = new DescribeInstancesCommand({});
    const EC2Data = await EC2Clients.send(EC2Command);
    return EC2Data;
    }
    let InstancesList = new Array();
for(let i=0;i<AWSRegion.length;i++){
    try{
    let EC2Data = await getEC2Instances(AWSRegion[i]);
InstancesList.push(EC2Data);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

}
```

it will return some instance result for me, but i want to get the instance which is running in last months. maybe this month the instance will be terminate or deleted, i still want to get the list of instance. is there any methods to get it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

as i noticed that, without cloudtrail, it is impossible to do this things.